# SQL After delete, insert or update trigger

Tags: sql-server, logging

Can you please give me a hand in starting this?

I have a table with this format:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ACS_ARMAZEM]
(
    [ARM_ID] [INT] IDENTITY(20000,1) NOT NULL,
    [ARM_DES] [NVARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
    [ARM_5_COD_DIG] [NVARCHAR](5) NOT NULL,
    [ARM_SIT] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [ARM_BIZ_TIP] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [ARM_STK_CTRL] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [ARM_DAT_CRI] [DATE] NOT NULL,
)
```

I need to log all changes (insert, delete or update) to a log table I have.

But I want to log the old and new values (even if a new row is inserted I want to log it as null in the old columns).

Best regards,

RL

Comment: Well, please show us what **YOU** have tried so far. We'll be glad to lend a helping hand - but SO isn't a free code-writing service where you just dump your requirements and someone writes the whole code for you .... start by reading the [official Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) on how to create a trigger

Answer (score 1):

Keeping it short, you need to use inserted and deleted tables. 
ie.

For insert/update:

```
UPDATE [YourTable]
   SET [YourColumn] = i + 1
OUTPUT deleted.[YourColumn], inserted.[YourColumn] INTO [YourLogTable]
WHERE i = 1;
```

(Here, deleted will give old values where inserted gives new)

For delete:

```
DELETE from [YourTable]
OUTPUT deleted.[YourColumn], NULL INTO [YourLogTable]
WHERE i = 2;
```

Of course, you will need to modify the statement to match with your log table structure. 
Please let me know if it helps. :)